# Z-order changed in activity transition animations on android 7.0 (nougat)?

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

I use custom animations for onBackPressed using

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  super.onBackPressed();
  overridePendingTransition(R.anim.zoom_in, R.anim.slide_outto_right);
}
```

On Android 6.x  the exit transition has the highest z-order, which means I can slide the leaving activity out while the "new" activity zooms in below it. Everythings fine on Marshmallow, but on Android 7.0 the z-order has reversed.

Is anybody else experiencing this?

Any fix suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

The solution to the problem was to add android:zAdjustment="..." to the anim xml:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     ...
     android:zAdjustment="top">
```

and

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     ...
     android:zAdjustment="bottom">
```

to the other animation.

Note: I sometime need to rebuild the project to see the anim changes kick through.

Comment: Is it possible that even this solution has been broken somewhere above API 28? Can't get it to work on my emulators. The entering activity displays over the exiting one no matter what I do.

Comment: Thats very likely. It is a long time ago I tested this :)

Comment: Sorry for bothering, I have since worked it out. I mistakenly put the attribute on the `Translate` animation instead of the outer `set`